# can do worse than V

Tags: modal-verbs

In "You can do worse than become a lawyer" (a more common alternative is "You could do worse than"), what does the "can" mean? Some people say it is used to indicate possibility, but there are different types of possibility. What kind of possibility does the "can" indicate?

In affirmative sentences, "can" seems to indicate a tendency, not tied to a one-time occasion. "He can be at home now" is thus an incorrect version of "He could/may/might be at home now," whereas "It can get really cold in the winter there" seems fine. Is the "can" in "You can do worse than ask John for help" an unusual word choice for this reason?

Note also that "can do worse" can presumably also be used with third-person subjects. E.g. "He can do worse than marry Sarah."

Comment: It’s the same can as in “You can get an ice cream cone at the candy store.”

Comment: On the contrary- it ***is*** a general statement.  It is the more colloquial form of “One can do worse than become...”

Comment: @Jim In your example, "can" has generic applicability. It is essentially the same as "Anyone can buy an ice cream there" or "Ice cream cones are sold at that store." But "You can do worse than become a lawyer" is targeted at the listener only. It is not intended as a general statement like "Anyone should become a lawyer."

Comment: @Jim Sorry that I deleted my comment after you commented on an earlier version.

Comment: @Jim But consider " He could/can do worse than marry Eleanor." Is it a general statement? Not very likely.

Comment: It really depends on context whether it applies to the listener only or is a general statement.  Without context I would interpret it as a general statement. But in a different context it certainly could be specific to the listener. (In reference to the “You can” sentence, not the “He can”)

Comment: Well, I'm interested in the interpretation of "can" in "can do worse than V" as an advice-giving sentence. It does not matter whether "he" or "you" is the subject.

Comment: So that brings us back to my first comment.

Comment: @Jim If "He can do worse than marry Eleanor" is correct, the "can" is certainly different from the "can" in "You can get an ice cream cone at that candy store." The former is not a general statement.

Comment: I don’t see why general vs specific makes a difference in whst ***can*** means.

Comment: The general vs. specific difference explains why "can" is incorrect in "He can be at home now" but fine "It can get really cold in the winter there."

Comment: No, I don’t think that’s true.

Comment: Do you think "can" is correct in "A: Where's John? B: I'm not sure. He can be at home"?

Comment: No I don’t. But I don’t think that’s because of a general vs specific thing.

Comment: How do you explain the contrast in acceptability between "He can be at home now" and "It can get really cold in the winter there"? Or between "He can be at home" and "He can get really angry sometimes" (the latter describing a tendency)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'there are different kinds of possibility'? Are you essentially asking for a probability estimate? Is your question  'Does "You could do worse than ..." connote/denote a lower probability-of-success estimate by the speaker than "You can do worse than ..."?'?

Comment: To express the kind of possibility in "He could/may/might be at home now," "can" cannot be used. But to express the kind of possibility in "He can get really angry," "can" is correct. So, there is more than one kind of possibility. What kind of possibility is involved in "He can do worse than become a lawyer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common expression is ***could*** *do worse than*, not ***can*** *do worse than*.

This is demonstrated by [Google's Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can%20do%20worse%20than%2Ccould%20do%20worse%20than&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20do%20worse%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20do%20worse%20than%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccan%20do%20worse%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20do%20worse%20than%3B%2Cc0):

[image: "Could do worse than" versus "can do worse than."]

The chart clearly shows that the *could* construction is far more common.

The use of *can* is a simple replacement of *could*, and it should be interpreted to mean the same thing as *could* in this context (in other words, possibility).

Any analysis of *can* here should be treated in the same way as an analysis of *could*. Focusing on definitions and senses of *can* is a red herring, inasmuch as it's meant to be taken synonymously with *could* in this phrase.

---

As an analogy, these two expressions are meant to express the same thing:

> I **couldn't** care less.
>   I **could** care less.

Although some people complain about what they think is the incorrect use of *could* (because it means the opposite of *couldn't*), in point of fact, people use both expressions in an identical fashion.

Short of analyzing and prescriptively debating the specific word used (*couldn't* or *could*), the two expressions are descriptively synonymous.

In the same way, the expression ***can*** *do worse than* means the same thing as the expression ***could*** *do worse than*. It's just that some people have come to use *can* instead of *could*.

Comment: Yes, the irony of the expression depends on the 'do worse than' part, not the can/could. Actually, it sounds like Yiddish gallows humor. Why would anyone want to do worse?

Comment: Are you among those who use "can do worse than V"?

Comment: @Apollyon I *personally* say *could* or *couldn't*. But if I ***did*** use *can* or *can't*, that's just a word. It doesn't change the meaning of the expression. In that phrase, *can* has exactly the same sense as *could*. To treat it differently is to misunderstand the expression and analyze it outside of its context. Although it's not as common, people say *I **could** care less* instead of *I **couldn't** care less.* Although the *words* mean opposite things, the *expressions* are meant in the identical sense.

Comment: I have added an expansion of that comment to my answer.

Comment: If you do not speak the dialect that uses "can do worse than V," it is dangerous to jump to the conclusion that "can do worse than V" and "could do worse than V" are interchangeable.

Comment: @Apollyon No, it's not. I *do* know people who use that phrase, and I *do* hear that phrase being used. (All among native English speakers, and in exactly an analogous way to *I **could** care less.*) I know perfectly well what the common meaning of the phrase is. I don't have to speak every combination of all words to understand what a specific combination I've never spoken before means, or to use it acceptably and fluently.

Comment: Can "you could do worse than V" be paraphrased as "you could do worse than if you V"?

Comment: @Apollyon At the very least, that sounds bizarre. So, on idiomatic grounds, I would say no. It's a stock phrase and has very few variations in common use. (That variation isn't one of them.)

Comment: I'm asking whether the idiomatic expression means that literally.

Comment: *You could do worse than if you X* is ungrammatical. The saying aside, it should either be *you could do worse if you X* or *you could do worse than X*.